# Continue statement in while loop python

Tags: python, while-loop, break, continue

I am a beginner in python and I am having trouble with this code:

```
count = 0

while count <15:
   if count == 5:
      continue
   print(count)
   count += 1
```

When the value of count = 5 it stops the loop as if there was a break statement.
Why is it so?
Please help!

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match the behaviour you describe.

Comment: It does not stop, it becomes an infinite loop, since `count` is no longer updated. It just stops printing stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continue statement in Python returns the control to the beginning of the current loop. When encountered, the loop starts next iteration without executing the remaining statements in the current iteration. When count becomes 5 in your loop it remains 5 since the loop is returned to the start without incrementing count.The following code may help you get it :

```
count = 0
while count < 15 :
   count += 1
   if count == 5 :
     continue 
print(count)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `continue` statement ignores the rest of the loop and returns back to the top. The count value is never updated since the `count += 1` statement is **after** `continue` ignored, thus from this point, count is always 5 and the `continue` statement is always executed. The print statement is also never executed past 4.

It does **not** break the loop, the loop is still running.

```
count = 0

while count <15:
  if count == 5:
    continue

  # The following is ignored after count = 4
  print(count)
  count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a `pass` statement instead of `continue` and change your indentation (this is assuming you want to print numbers from 0-15 but not 5).

`pass` is the equivalent of doing nothing

```py
count = 0

while count <15:
   if count == 5:
      pass
   else:
      print(count)
   count += 1
```

`continue` takes the code to the end of the loop. This means that when `count` is 5, the loop goes to the end and the value of count never increments and gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Take a look at [break, pass and continue statements](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm)